# How to resolve circular import error for a complex project structure?

Tags: python, oop, importerror, circular-dependency

I am working on python project and want to structure it well. Specifically, I want to avoid having all the classes in the same file. This is how I ran into a circular import error problem. Please see the current structure of the project below:

- main.py
- src (Sources Root directory)

  - chess

    - _*init*_.py
    - board.py
    - chess_class.py
    - pieces (Directory)

      - _*init*_.py
      - piece_base.py
      - pieces_classes.py

Content of main.py:

```
from chess import Chess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Chess().play()
```

Content of src/chess/_*init*_.py:

```
from .chess_class import Chess
```

Content of src/chess/board.py:

```
from .pieces import *

class Board:
    ...
```

Content of src/chess/chess_classes:

```
from .board import Board

class Chess:
    def play(self):
        print("hi")
```

Content of src/chess/pieces/_*init*_.py:

```
from .pieces_classes import Queen, Rook
```

Content of src/chess/pieces/piece_base.py:

```
from ..board import Board

class Piece:
    """Base class for all pieces."""
    ...
```

Content of src/chess/pieces/pieces_classes:

```
from .piece_base import Piece
from ..board import Board

class Queen(Piece):
    ...

class Rook(Piece):
    ...
```

Running main.py raises ImportError.

Order of imports:

1. from chess import Chess
2. from .chess_class import Chess
3. from .board import Board
4. from .pieces import *
5. from .pieces_classes import Queen, Rook
6. from .piece_base import Piece
7. from ..board import Board

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Board from partially initialized module chess.board        (most likely due to a circular import)
```

So far, I have tried importing the entire board module in piece_base and pieces_classes using import chess.board, but it did not help. Other solutions found on the internet suggest importing from within the class, which may significantly harm performance, or combining the classes into one file, which I am also against because I would like to keep the structure as is if possible.

Any solutions or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

I am using Python 3.11.1 and PyCharm. I have marked the src directory as Sources Root for PyCharm.

This is a link to the branch on my GitHub that I push my commits to:
https://github.com/vldryz/chessgame/tree/feature/chess-redesign 
The project is not finished yet. But it faces the same issue.

Please let me know if you require any additional information.

Edit: 
**Solution**
As @KarlKnechtel mentioned, my project had a design issue rather than an implementation issue. The pieces should not have imported the Board class in the first place, as it is not their responsibility to track the state of the board. Thus, removing the Board imports resolves the problem, as the circular import error no longer arises.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where the code in e.g. `piece_base.py` says `from ..board import Board`, **why**? Why does the code that explains how a piece works, need to know anything about boards?

Comment: Hello @KarlKnechtel and thank you! The reason for that is to add type hints. I want each piece to have a `legal_moves` method, which would find all legal moves given the state of the board `Board.state`. This may not be the most optimal solution, so if you have any suggestion, I would love to hear them. Thank you!

Comment: The logic for figuring out whether a move is legal - and consequently, refining the list of legal moves - logically belongs in the board, not the piece. The piece can tell the board about places that it *could theoretically* move, without considering other pieces. You will want to be able to configure the logic that looks for captures, blocks etc. so that it either does or doesn't care about checks (do you understand why?). But it's the purpose of the board to know where pieces are; it's not the responsibility of pieces to understand their board position.

Comment: But this is really a **design** issue rather than an implementation issue. You might instead have better luck asking a question like this on e.g. [gamedev.se].

Comment: That makes complete sense. I am not sure why I haven't thought about it myself. Thank you for your suggestion! I have tested the programme without Board imports in pieces files and it runs. I will be more observant next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have rightly concluded that this situation is *terrible*.

The solution is straightforward.

1. Beef up `test_Chess_classes.py` (or write a similar TestCase) so it detects the current `import` lossage (a Red test).
2. Go back to a previous code rev where the test is Green.
3. Re-introduce your recent re-org refactors little by little, while keeping it Green.

Typical reason that a developer will be tempted to have A `import B` and B `import A` is the relationship *should* be A imports B, but B wants some common / utility method in A. So we evict that method to a new C module, which A + B both import, and life is good.

EDIT

In particular, go back to `$ git checkout 3ceaff`, where we see:

```
--- a/src/pieces/piece_base.py
+++ b/src/pieces/piece_base.py
@@ -4,6 +4,7 @@
 from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
 
 # Dependencies
+from board import Board
 from utils import Colour
 
...
+    def _available_moves(self, start, board: Board) -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
```

Don't do that (as discussed).

Back out the bad edit.
Refactor so your subsequent improvements work without the circular design flaw.
Prior to each local commit, run a sanity check (maybe `pytest` ? )
to verify the codebase is in sensible shape.

Always have a working system! (For some definition of "working".)

---

> ```
> from .pieces import *
> ```

nit: Don't do that. Prefer to list the handful of identifiers you actually need.

But that's the least of your worries ATM.

---

Going forward, ask GitHub to run a CI/CD integration
for you which will Fail The Build if unit tests are Red.
You want to know sooner than later if a recent edit messed things up.

Comment: Pushing code to GitHub for the specific purpose of *finding out whether there is a problem* is a terrible idea. Some measure of testing should be done locally. Aside from that, someone who is implementing a simple command-line chess board program does not need to learn about CI/CD. Using version control at all is (sadly) ahead of the curve. This is not someone who needs to try to support multiple versions of Python, or figure out which ones are supported, or manage a dependency matrix.

Comment: Dear @J_H, thank you for your comments. Indeed, as @KarlKnechtel mentioned, I do not want to dive that deep into development process yet. I am a Data Scientist that wishes to get more familiar with Python OOP by improving the chess programme that I had written half a year ago. I would highly appreciate a more detailed explanation on how can I fix my code to make it work as it. The `test` file on GitHub hasn't been updated yet.